# how to update reference of an object(mutable) used as key in hashmap after setter called on it?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I had attended one interview on core java. Interviewer asked me about key used in hashmap.
The one specific question i had no clue is here:  Immutable key should be preferred, but what if you use one mutable key and put some entry in it and then you need to call setters. How will you get the entries made by these key which has different hasCode (wrt to when it was used to inset element) now?